# Trigonometric Differentiation. Height of a wave.

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

The movement of the crest of a wave is modelled with the equation $h(t)=0.3\cos 3t+0.4\sin 3t$. Find the maximum height of the wave and the time at which it occurs.

I have come up until here. please tell me if I did it right or wrong and how do I find the time the maximum height is at?

$$h(t) = 0.3 \cos 3t + 0.4 \sin 3t $$

To find the maximum or minimum, take the first derivative 
and equate it to 0.

$$\begin{align*} \frac{dh}{dt} &= -0.3*3 \sin 3 t +0.4 * 3 \cos 3t \\
\tan 3t &= 1.2/0.9 \\ 
3t &= 53.06\end{align*}$$

The maximum value is

$$h(t) = 0.3 \cos(53.06) + 0.4 \sin(53.06)=0.487 $$
This is the maximum.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the maximum will be at $0.5=\sqrt{0.3^2+0.4^2}$... it's easier to see this (and easier to do the problem) if you combine the sine and cosine into a single cosine (or sine) of the form $R\cos(3t+T)$

Comment: So is my answer incorrect? And sorry I dont understand what you mean, could you please write it out, even on a piece of paper and take a picture of it please! thanks for the help though.

Comment: The thing is that rounding causes loss of precision. Let $3t=\tan^{-1}\frac{4}{3}$, then $\cos 3t=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2}}=\dfrac{3}{5},\, \sin 3t=\cos 3t \tan 3t= \frac{3}{5}\cdot \frac{4}{3} = \frac{4}{5}$, plugging these two back yields the correct answer of $0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the compound angle identity $\sin(A+B)=\sin A \cos B+\cos A\sin B$, we can re-write $h(t)=0.3\cos(3t)+0.4\sin(3t)$ by letting:

$$0.3\cos(3t)+0.4\sin(3t)=R\sin(3t+T)$$ where we need to find $R$ and $T$.

$$0.3\cos(3t)+0.4\sin(3t)=R\sin(3t+T)=R\sin(3t)\cos T+ R\cos(3t)\sin T$$
comparing coefficients of $\sin(3t)$ and $\cos(3t)$ gives:
$$R\cos T = 0.3$$ and $$R\sin T = 0.4$$.
Dividing one by the other gives $\tan T = 4/3$ and squaring both and adding gives $R^2=0.4^2+0.3^2$

This gives you $T$ and $R$, allowing you to find that $h(t)=0.5 \sin(3t+T)$ which has a maximum of $0.5$ when $3t+T=\pi/2$ i.e. when $t={\pi/2-T\over 3}$

Comment: alright thanks. that makes sense, but now how do you i find the time the maximum happens at?

Comment: That's the last line in my answer... The idea is that the sine function has a maximum of 1 and that this happens when its argument is $\pi/2$  or 90°